# How to migrate SWF plugin panel for InDesign CS4 to InDesign CC2014?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm trying to migrate some legacy code for a patch panel written in Flex / Flash for InDesign to work in CC2014. Currently, it is falling over as there is a var "InDesign" that was previously set but is no longer set.

EG: In order to get a reference to the app object, the code was using;

```
app = InDesign.app; //this variable is already present if this is run by indesign.
```

But "InDesign" has not been set.

Two questions;
1. Has the object name changed, if so, what to?
2. Is there any additional step I need to do to get InDesign / Flash integration working for Patch Panel?

And a further one...
3. Assuming that this is still possible and still supported, how can I debug using Flash Builder with InDesign?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flash/Flex Panels are deprecated. Take a look at Extension Builder 3. You can build panels for ID CC 2014 with HTML5 and Javascript/Extendscript now.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/extensionbuilder3/

To your questions.

A1) In extendscript you can address InDesign CC like this.

You can ommit the target if you want.

```
#target "indesign-10" 
var indesign = app;
alert(indesign.version);
```

A2) Well. As I said. The Flash/Flex panels are deprecated.
A3) You can still use their eclipse plugin to run and debug panels.